# is there a way to solve the pylance error?

Tags: python, random, import, generator, pylance

i get this error everytime i run my code
( "(" was not closed Pylance [4,9] )
and i really can't find any solution for it guys please help me :(
and i really don't know what to do i just started learning py and i really wanna keep going so who's please going to be my saver :)

````
import copy

story = (
    "I can't believe it's already {} ! " +
    "I can't wait to put on my {} and visit every {} in my nighborhood. " +
    "This year, I am going to dress up as (a) {} with {} {} . " +
    "Before I {} , I make sure to grab my {} {} to hold all of my {}. " +
    "Finally, all of my {} are ready to go ! " +
)


word_dict = {
    'Holiday noun':['Holiday'],
    'Noun':['cosplay','custom outfit','halloween clothes'],
    'Place nouns':['corner','place','street'],
    'Person':['Frankenstein','Princess','Queen','Cop'],
    'Adjective':['creepy','shiny','lovely'],
    'Body part (plural)':['arms','eye lashes','glasses'],
    'Verb':['go','go out','wolk out'],
    'Adjective':['little','big','colored','beautiful'],
    'Noun':['bag','handbag','carryall'],
    'Food':['candies','sweets','bonbons'],
    'Plural noun':['things','stuff','gear'],
}

def get_word(type, local_dict):
    words = local_dict[type]
    cnt = len(words)-1
    index = randint(0, cnt)
    return local_dict[type].pop(index)

def create_story():
    local_dict = copy.deepcopy(word_dict)
    return story.format(
        get_word('Holiday noun',local_dict),
        get_word('Noun',local_dict),
        get_word('Place nouns',local_dict),
        get_word('Person',local_dict),
        get_word('Adjective',local_dict),
        get_word('Body part (plural)',local_dict),
        get_word('Verb',local_dict),
        get_word('Adjective',local_dict),
        get_word('Noun',local_dict),
        get_word('Food',local_dict),
        get_word('Plural noun',local_dict),
    )

print("Story 1: ")
print(create_story())
print()
print("Story 2: ")
print(create_story()) ```
````

Comment: instead of randint, import random and write 'random.randint', also, you have an extra plus in 'story'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute your code, it will tell where the first non-excepted character is:

```
python .\nietchez.py
  File "C:\Users\nietchez\source\nietchez.py", line 9
    )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So there is something wrong right before the `)`. Remove the `+` sign, and also, add the random library:

```py
import copy
from random import randint

story = (
    "I can't believe it's already {} ! " +
    "I can't wait to put on my {} and visit every {} in my nighborhood. " +
    "This year, I am going to dress up as (a) {} with {} {} . " +
    "Before I {} , I make sure to grab my {} {} to hold all of my {}. " +
    "Finally, all of my {} are ready to go ! "
)
```

Furthermore, you don't even need the `+` between the lines:

```py
story = (
    "I can't believe it's already {} ! "
    "I can't wait to put on my {} and visit every {} in my nighborhood. "
    "This year, I am going to dress up as (a) {} with {} {} . 1"
    "Before I {} , I make sure to grab my {} {} to hold all of my {}. "
    "Finally, all of my {} are ready to go ! "
)
```

Comment: thank you so much that worked <33 !!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Finally, all of my {} are ready to go ! " +
```

you need to remove the + at the end of that line

and you are going to need to import random to use the randint functions

```
from random import randint
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `story` has excess `+` operator at the end, so you must remove it. Also your code doesn't import `randint` function from the module `random`, so add `from random import random` string at the top of your code.